# Question about Django?

Tags: django

sorry, I'm beginner in python programming language

I searched for good python framwork...
I found Django framework and did a simple app using it .

**can I upload the final django project to any host site ?**

Comment: It depends on your hosting.  Very cheap shared hosting providers may only support PHP and/or Perl CGI, in which case Django will be useless to you.  Python/Ruby support in various guises tends to be a feature of better hosting providers but the conditions are highly variable.  Best be more specific about what you need and expect.

Comment: do you mean any framework ? can I write pure python site (without any framework) and upload it on of these normal hosting providers

Comment: is tornado is the same as django . can I upload tornado project to normal host providers

Answer (score 1):

No, your host will need to support Django. Most of the cheaper hosting providers (GoDaddy, 1and1, etc.) are unlikely to include Django support. Hosting it on a VPS is probably your best bet, but requires more server administration expertise.

Comment: Sort of. Google recommends (http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/django.html) Django-nonrel (http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel). I've heard Django on Google's infrastructure can be a pain. You're probably best off using Django on the database it was designed for - SQL.